# US ZIP Code in center between 2 ZIP codes?

Tags: c#, zipcode

How could I determine the closest 'center' ZIP code between two given US ZIP Codes?

Answer (score 3):

- map zip codes to latitude/longitude (google returned http://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/)
- calculate geographical midpoint between the two coordinate pairs (e.g. http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html)
- look up the closest zip code for the resulting coordinate.